# What is Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1?

Tags: c++, sdk

I am going to use Cython for my project. As a prerequisite, [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950) should be installed in order to link with the right runtime.

However, I already have Virtual Studio 2012 installed in my computer, so I am wondering if this is still necessary?

And, what is it? Is it different from Visual Studio? I found some introduction about it, and seems it is already included in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2012 contain framework 4.5 till now and yes they both are same.
since, cython was originally made on VS2008 so it has some issue to later framework.
some cool guys solved this issue on vs 2010. 
You can have more detail on this links

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/cython-users/12a3ab97em/cython-and-linking-to-multiple-dlls

http://magic-smoke.blogspot.in/2012/07/building-pyliblo-on-windows-using.html